# HTTP POST Data with Image from WebForm to .NET Web API, JSON too big

Tags: webforms, json.net, httpwebrequest, asp.net-apicontroller, image-file

I'm working with a C# webform application that needs to send an image to an API method. The POST gets executed in the webform app and it hits the API POST method, but the JObject parameter in the API method is NULL but the JSON data in the webform is created with no problem. If I pass all the data excluding the image, the JObject is not null, so that tells me the image(byte) is too big to pass. I've tried to compress the image but that doesn't work, tried enctype="multipart/form-data" as part of the form, I've also increased the jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" to int32.max in the web.config in the API app and web app but that doesn't work. Not sure what to try next, but will keep searching, any help would be much appreciated. The webform and API controller code is posted below:

Button Click code:

```
    HttpPostedFile _File = ImageUpload.PostedFile;
    int fileSize = _File.ContentLength;
    string contentType = _File.ContentType;
    string fileName = _File.FileName;

    byte[] bytes;

    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(_File.InputStream))
    {
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(_File.ContentLength);
    }

    ImageModel _ImgModel = new ImageModel();

    _ImgModel.Name = fileName;
    _ImgModel.ContentType = contentType;
    _ImgModel.Data = bytes;
    _ImgModel.idPersonFK = 1;

    string apiURL = "http://localhost:XYZZ/api/Image/InsertImage";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(apiURL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_ImgModel);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    using (dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.  
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    response.Close();
```

Model Class:

```
public class ImageModel 
{
    public long ImageID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> idPersonFK { get; set; }
}
```

API Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Image/InsertImage")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public HttpResponseMessage Insert(JObject input)
{
    try
    {
        //Code that will insert the image but input parameter is NULL;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "");
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"
```

Comment: JSON in asp.net isn't great for uploading large binaries because the binary gets encoded as a single Base64 string, which Newtonsoft will materialize as a single `string`, causing memory problems.  Have you considered using an alternate format?  E.g. if you are using [tag:asp.net-core] then `IFormFile` may work for you, see [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and [Upload files and JSON in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41367602).

Comment: [How to Upload Image Via WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31839449) is another option.

Comment: Dbc, it's not .NET Core but Web API 2 which was built by an external company and it was built upon JSON. There would be a lot of work to to change it to another format (XML). An alternative would be to have the webform save the file(s) to a temp folder on the IIS web server and have the API pull them from there and then save it to the DB or call the API POST method one picture at a time. Thank you for your input DBC, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My bad (didn't have my morning coffee), it would help if the picture size I was trying to upload was around 2mb instead of 5mb, so I will need to limit my image upload size.

In my case since I need to upload a minimum of 3 images and max of 6, they will have to be done one by one as the JSON string will be too big.

If there is a better or more efficient way, feel free to leave me a message.

Thank you.